# C# order placement with the equals sign

Tags: c#, this

Wondering if there is a difference between the two:

```
public Bee (double weight) 
    {
        this.weight = weight;
```

and

```
public Bee (double weight) 
    {
        weight = this.weight;
```

Does it change the meaning if you switch what's left and right of the equal "=" sign?

Comment: What do you understand each of those lines to do? Try thinking about it if you renamed the parameter to your function to say `wibble`, rather than `weight`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The meaning most definitely changes. One assigns the value of `weight` to `this.weight` and the other assigns the value of `this.weight` to `weight`.

Answer (score 3):

The latter will assign the value stored in your class' `weight` field and assign it to the `weight` argument that was passed into your method.

The former will do the opposite.

Basically, `this.weight` refers to your class' `weight` field, where `weight` refers to the method's argument. If there was no `weight` variable in the scope of the method, you could still use `weight` to refer to the class field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `this` keyword indicates the variable is a class instance variable. Without the `this` keyword, the local weight parameter will be used.

The following example assigns the parameter passed into the constructor to the class instance variable of the same name.

Example class:

```
public class Bee
{
    double weight;

    public Bee(double weight)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They are different.  `this.weight` is referring to a property or variable on the class and `weight` is referring to the parameter in the method.

Let's take an example:

```
public class Bee
{
   private double weight;      

   public Bee (double weight)
   {
      this.weight = weight;
   }
}
```

If I wanted to change the parameter weight in the function, I could do this:

```
public class Bee
{
   private double weight;      

   public Bee (double initialWeight)
   {
      this.weight = initialWeight;
   }
}
```

And If I wanted to change the internal variable weight, I would do this:

```
public class Bee
{
   private double internalWeight;      

   public Bee (double weight)
   {
      this.internalWeight = weight;
   }
}
```

As you can see either change makes it much clearer what is going on here, it also helps you understand what is being set on each call.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the single `=` is the [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) - it assigns the value of the right-hand expression to the variable on the left-hand side. That being the case, the order certainly does matter.

If you're looking for a logical equality comparison, you would use [the `==` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) - of course, doing so in the code you've provided would be pointless: the statement would *return* `true` or `false` as its result, and you would then need to *assign* that result or do something else useful with it.

Comment: I've dismissed your flag as helpful, as the issue has been resolved. See [this post on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165096/markdown-links-and-images-are-producing-incorrect-html) for a dev follow-up.